# Bottom border for list view in android

Tags: android, listview, border

I'm trying to add a bottom border my listview in android
The code i used is

```
<ListView 
  android:id="@+id/listview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_weight="1" 
  android:scrollbars="horizontal" 
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"
  />
```

It is working when there is only lest no of items. But not working when no of items is more
I mean when the items cannot display in on screen
Thanks

The entire layout i used

>

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/navigationbar"
    >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/search_icon"/>

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<EditText   
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/categoryListEditText"/>    

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/switch_list_button"
    android:id="@+id/switchListsButton"/>

</LinearLayout>
    <TextView   style="@style/firstBannerTextView"
    android:text="Type a category name to filter the List."/>



    <TextView   
    style="@style/secondBannerTextView"     
    android:id="@+id/categoryList"
    />

<ListView 
  android:id="@+id/listview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_weight="1" 
  android:scrollbars="horizontal" 
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"
  />
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire layout? You will need to have the ListView in context of the whole layout in order to determine how to anchor your listview to the bottom border or at least make sure the bottom border does not get overtaken by the listview.

Comment: Thank You for considering my question... i have added the full layout with my question... Thanks

Comment: anambullan: What do you consider a "bottom border" to be?

Comment: Actually the bottom border i considered is, the divider of each list view is not there for the last element. I'm searching for giving a border to the last element also....Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Labeep if you check the dividers are only within the listitems it misses the bottom as well as the top. Try using the shape  tag and set is as a background to your listVIew.

Or in case you need a bottom divider only?

Just have a view tag.